# MARKLOGIC Boot Test Connection to http://localhost:8002 refused

Tags: marklogic

When using the MarkLogic java-api-client I execute the boot-test.sh

```
sh src/test/resources/boot-test.sh
```

I get

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to
>   http://localhost:8002 refused

Is this simply an authentication issue?

I've changed the passwords in

```
java-client-api/src/main/resources/Example.properties
```

as well as the password in which I believe is the one in question

```
java-client-api/src/test/java/com/marklogic/client/test/util/TestServerBootstrapper.java
```

Although I still get connection refused. I've confirmed that the server has the management port set to 8002.

Also having the same general issue not being able to connect to MarkLogic with running curl on the server

curl --anyauth --user  admin:xxxx -X PUT -d@'./one.xml'  -H "Content-type: application/xml"  'http://localhost:8000/LATEST/documents?uri=/xml/one.xml'

curl: (7) couldn't connect to host

I can access the server through the 8001 interface so I assume it's some configuration error but haven't been able to figure it out. I've basically installed MarkLogic on three digital ocean centos 6 server, changed the admin passwords, set up a cluster of three nodes that are connected and created a database and three forests on each node. Otherwise I believe everything is default.

I installed the following on the centos 6 server

```
yum -y install glibc.i686 gdb.x86_64 redhat-lsb.x86_64
rpm -i /tmp/MarkLogic-RHEL6-8.0-5.x86_64.rpm
yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel
yum install -y git
yum install -y httpd
service httpd start
yum install -y nano
yum install -y tree
yum install -y wget
wget http://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/dchen/apache-maven/epel-apache-maven.repo -O /etc/yum.repos.d/epel-apache-maven.repo
yum install apache-maven
yum update
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Regards
Conteh

Comment: You say `I've basically installed MarkLogic on three digital ocean centos 6 server`. Are you sure you should be accessing `localhost`, and not some other address?

Comment: What version of MarkLogic server are you using?

Comment: @grtjn I was executing curl from the server that had one of the nodes installed as well as the java code. I also ran the code with the domain and had the same results. I also ran the java locally from my machine with the domain and had the same error.  I had the java code running well on my local machine connecting to a local docker container with marklogic 8.03

Comment: @SamMeffod I'm running 8.05 MarkLogic-RHEL6-8.0-5.x86_64.rpm

Comment: @SamMefford I've added a list of installation steps as well. Perhaps there is something wrong there.

Comment: Could you verify that the port 8002 is listening? You may get help from https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/s1-server-ports.html. If it is not, you should open that port first.

Comment: Thanks @NavinRawat you were correct. I did a search for marklogic and iptables and came across the following script created for centos digital ocean https://github.com/jmakeig/marklogic-bootstrapping/blob/master/digitalocean/bootstrap.sh which I'll test

Comment: That script seems to work for the most part however the ./configure --with-http_ssl_module --with-pcre=../pcre-8.32 --with-zlib=../zlib-1.2.7 line doesn't quite fit with the adjustments above it to how pcre-devel and zlib-devel were changed to install with yum.

Comment: Are you able to run curl for port 8002?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following worked as an updated version of https://github.com/jmakeig/marklogic-bootstrapping/blob/master/digitalocean/bootstrap.sh The installation works fine thus far.

The bootstrap code executed properly

java-client-api]# sh src/test/resources/boot-test.sh
Created java-unittest server on 8012 port for java-unittest database
Bootstrapped rest server for unit tests on port 8012
Installed bootstrap extension.  Response is HTTP/1.1 204 Created [Server: MarkLogic, Content-Length: 0, Connection: Keep-Alive, Keep-Alive: timeout=5]
Invoked bootstrap extension.  Response is HTTP/1.1 200 OK [Server: MarkLogic, Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8, Content-Length: 468, Connection: Keep-Alive, Keep-Alive: timeout=5]

Thanks much for all the help

```
#!/bin/bash

# MarkLogic 8.0-5 Digital Ocean Centos 6.7 64bit

# log everything to a file
exec &> $HOME/stackscript.log

# yum -y: assume yes, -q: quiet
yum -yq update
yum -yq install nano tree wget gcc gcc-c++ make zlib-devel pcre-devel openssl-devel java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel
wget http://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/dchen/apache-maven/epel-apache-maven.repo -O /etc/yum.repos.d/epel-apache-maven.repo
yum -yq install apache-maven

yum -yq groupinstall 'Development Tools'
yum -yq install glibc glibc.i686 lsb

curl -o MarkLogic-RHEL6-8.0-5.x86_64.rpm "https://developer.marklogic.com/download/binaries/8.0/MarkLogic-RHEL6-8.0-5.x86_64.rpm?t=5bfgbebCkZ/1KkgggvKp30&email=xxx%40gmail.com"
rpm -iv MarkLogic-RHEL6-8.0-5.x86_64.rpm
#rm MarkLogic-RHEL6-8.0-5.x86_64.rpm



# Set Linux huge pages
echo "vm.nr_hugepages = 292" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
sysctl -p

# Flush all curren

t rules from iptables
iptables -F

#First, we start with blocking null packets
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL NONE -j DROP

#The next pattern to reject is a syn-flood attack.
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW -j DROP

#XMAS packets, also a recon packet.
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL ALL -j DROP

# Set access for localhost
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

#Now we can allow web server traffic:
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

#Now, let's allow users use our SMTP servers:
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 465 -j ACCEPT

# Allow SSH connections on tcp port 22
# This is essential when working on remote servers via SSH to prevent locking yourself out of the system
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

#allow us to use outgoing connections (ie. ping from VPS or run software updates);
iptables -I INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT 

# We will block everything else, and allow all outgoing connections.
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P INPUT DROP

# Note eth0 interface
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 7999 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8000 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8001 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8002 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8010 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8012 -j ACCEPT

service iptables save 

mkdir -p src && cd src
nginxVersion="1.8.1"
wget http://nginx.org/download/nginx-$nginxVersion.tar.gz
tar -xzf nginx-$nginxVersion.tar.gz 
ln -sf nginx-$nginxVersion nginx

cd nginx

./configure \
--user=nginx                          \
--group=nginx                         \
--prefix=/etc/nginx                   \
--sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx           \
--conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf     \
--pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid         \
--lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock       \
--error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log \
--http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log \
--with-http_gzip_static_module        \
--with-http_stub_status_module        \
--with-http_ssl_module                \
--with-pcre                           \
--with-file-aio                       \
--with-http_realip_module             \
--without-http_scgi_module            \
--without-http_uwsgi_module           \
--without-http_fastcgi_module

make
make install

useradd -r nginx

wget -O /etc/init.d/nginx "https://gist.github.com/sairam/5892520/raw/b8195a71e944d46271c8a49f2717f70bcd04bf1a/etc-init.d-nginx"
chmod +x /etc/init.d/nginx

chkconfig --add nginx
chkconfig --level 345 nginx on


#Manually Configure
#nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf to set types_hash_bucket_size and server_names_hash_bucket_size which needs to be increased.

#http {
#    include       mime.types;
#    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    # add the below 2 lines under http around line 20
#    types_hash_bucket_size 64;
#    server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;

#service MarkLogic start
#service nginx start
```

Comment: btw with that setup I ended up when running "mvn test" within the java-api-client
 getting Tests run: 111, Failures: 5, Errors: 21, Skipped: 0

Comment: @SamMefford I've attached the output of the java client api tests if there is interest in the results to the following google site.  Thought it might be of interest. https://sites.google.com/site/contehmarklogic/java-api-client-tests